# how to customise cluster icon in mapbox-gl?

Tags: mapbox, markerclusterer, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I want to implement clustering in my map.

I found example of simple clustering from [Mapbox Cluster Example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/)  but

[My code is here](http://pastebin.com/x2kFHzFv), where marker ==> {marker-symbol} is from studio.

but it is not working. Is it possible to achieve output of cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved By following code

```
var layers = [
    [150],
    [20],
    [0]
];
layers.forEach(function(layer, i) {
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "cluster-" + i,
        "source": "markers",
        "type": "symbol",
        "layout": {
            "text-field": "{point_count}",
            "text-font": [
                "Arial Unicode MS Bold"
            ],
            "text-size": 13,
            "text-anchor": "bottom",
            "icon-image": "emptyMarker",
            "icon-size": 0.25
        },
        "paint": {
            "text-color": "white"
        },
        "filter": i === 0 ? [">=", "point_count", layer[0]] : ["all", [">=", "point_count", layer[0]],
            ["<", "point_count", layers[i - 1][0]]
        ]
    });
});
map.addLayer({
    "id": "cluster-count",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": "markers"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is:
1. You calculate all the **center's bound of the children's marker**,
and store them as clusters's marker
2. You have to control the Zoom action, 
if it is **greater than 15** then you only show the **children's marker**
else if it **lesser than 15** then you only show the **clusters's marker**

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion :)