# mapbox-gl. Points with same location show as regular polygon

Tags: mapbox, markerclusterer, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

So for 2 points:

`O-O`

for 3 poins:

`O
 / \
O   O`

etc.

For example I have 2 points with the same location. They overlap. I want to offset those markers and connect them with lines like in the image below:

[image]

Here I've found something but don't know if it applies here [how to customise cluster icon in mapbox-gl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524947/how-to-customise-cluster-icon-in-mapbox-gl)

I found something similar for carto https://carto.com/blog/stacking-chips-a-map-hack/

Comment: Maybe its just me but I don't understand the question nor the question title...

Comment: @Andi-lo added more description and image

Comment: This feature does not exist in mapbox-gl at the moment, but it's possible we will develop something to accommodate this use-case in the future.

Answer (score 1):

@rofrol, basically you can use a technique called "Spiderifier" to do it.

Here is the library for using in all framework
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapboxgl-spiderifier

If you're using ReactJS, here is another solution
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mapbox-gl-spiderifier